# Creating log directory in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to learn how to use tensorboard and I would like to have it run in my program. I do not understand how to create a log directory. These are the lines I have for running tensorboard.

```
   summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tensorflow/logdir', sess.graph_def)
   tensorboard --logdir=tensorflow/logdir
```

The error message that I got was

```
Cannot assign to operator
```

Comment: What error msg did you get? Do you mean ` tensorboard --logdir=/tensorflow/logdir`?

Comment: I tried /tensorflow/logdir but I got the same error "cannot assign to operator"

Comment: Sounds like a python error. When did you get it? When you write the summary or when you run the tensorboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line needs to be in your code (the python script), as it seems you put it:

> summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tensorflow/logdir',
>   sess.graph_def)

This line, however, you have to call from linux (and not from within the script):

> tensorboard --logdir=tensorflow/logdir

However, there is a lot more you need to do, before tensorboard really runs:
[How to create a Tensorflow Tensorboard Empty Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663081/how-to-create-a-tensorflow-tensorboard-empty-graph)

Comment: Is there a way I call the line from within the script

Comment: No, and why would you want to?

Comment: I am getting an error   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tensorflow'

Comment: Instead of using /tensorflow, try a directory in /tmp, like /tmp/tensorflow

Comment: tf.train.SummaryWriter is deprecated, instead use tf.summary.FileWriter.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial might disclose not very clear on the TensorFlow official website

I have stuck in the same issue before

But in order not to confuse you, i still use it as a guide here

**First Part (lines of codes in .py file)**

Just skip to [class tf.train.SummaryWriter](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter) in official guide

First, you need this lines of code in your .py file to create a dataflow graph

In tensorflow, a session is where the graph been created

```
#...create a graph...
# Launch the graph in a session.
sess = tf.Session()
```

Then, you also need to type in these lines into your code

```
# Create a summary writer, add the 'graph' to the event file.
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(< directory name you create>, sess.graph)
```

The logs folder will be generated in the *directory* you assigned after the .py file you created is executed

[Here](https://github.com/MorvanZhou/tutorials/blob/master/tensorflowTUT/tf15_tensorboard/full_code.py) is the sample code you can use

**Second Part (lines of code in your linux terminal)**

In your Linux terminal window, type in

```
tensorboard --logdir="path of your log file"
```

It will link to your log file automatically

**Last step (key in link into your browser)**

After key in

```
tensorboard --logdir="path of your log file"
```

It will generate a http link ,ex http://666.6.6.6:6006

Copy the http link into your web browser

Enjoy it!

**Be careful**

Do not go to the directory where the log file is **before** key in the line of code above

It might miss the log file

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp5EtBvwQbw&list=PLXO45tsB95cJHXaDKpbwr5fC_CCYylw1f&index=15) youtube video will explain more explicitly about this at 9:40

You also can take a look of how to launch tensorboard on [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html)

Hope you can show your data graph ASAP~

Answer (score 0):

for --colab

%tensorflow_version 2.x

from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

tensorboard_logdir = '/content/tensorboard/'
writer = SummaryWriter(tensorboard_logdir)

Comment: You appear to be importing `SummaryWriter` from pytorch, while the question is about tensorflow.