# tensorboard not displaying after it loads on browser

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorboard

I am implementing a GAN to generate fake tweets. I would like to visualize my model using Tensorboard but it's not displaying anything. This is my first time using Tensorboard, and I followed a tutorial on YouTube (https://gist.github.com/dandelionmane/4f02ab8f1451e276fea1f165a20336f1#file-mnist-py). When I run `tensorboard --logdir=/path_to_dir` it gives me a port, and this port takes me to Tensorboard, but nothing is displayed. Below is my code. Thank you!
**code deleted**
It's pretty long, so please ctrl-F to find the lines related to Tensorboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following line after you have defined your graph:

```
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

Look at the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter#add_graph).

Look at this question:

[How to create a Tensorflow Tensorboard Empty Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663081/how-to-create-a-tensorflow-tensorboard-empty-graph)