# How can I visualize the estimator Trained model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorboard

I have created a model with 3 hidden layers and trained it with the specific data-set.

How can I visualize the Model, with the neuron connections and weights at each iteration.

Here is the snippet of the python code :

```
#<ALL IMPORT STATEMENTS>
MODEL_DIR = <model_name>

def make_estimator(model_dir):
 config = run_config.RunConfig(model_dir=model_dir)
 feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=<number_of_feat_cols>)]
 return estimator.DNNClassifier(config=config, hidden_units=[<>,<>,<>],feature_columns=feat_cols,n_classes=2,optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001))

data = pd.read_csv(<csv_file>)

feat_data = data.drop('Type',axis=1)
feat_data_matrix = feat_data.as_matrix()

labels = data['Type']
labels_matrix = labels.as_matrix()

deep_model = make_estimator(MODEL_DIR)
input_fn = estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={'x':feat_data_matrix}, y=labels_matrix, shuffle=True, batch_size=10, num_epochs=1000)
tr_steps = <step_size>
deep_model.train(input_fn=input_fn,steps=tr_steps)
print ("Training Done")
```

In the code above, I have not created any tensorflow session, without it where can I implement the TensorBoard APIs for visualizing the model ?

Answer (score 1):

By using the `Python API` simply call the method `tf.summary.FileWriter`

Then if you load the file written by the SummaryWriter into TensorBoard, the graph is shown.

You have to load the graph like this:

```
# Launch the graph.
current_session = tf.Session()
current_session.run(init)

# Create a summary writer, add the 'graph' to the event file.
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(<some-directory>, current_session.graph)
```

See [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter)

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.training' has no attribute 'SummaryWriter' Got this error

Comment: try this instead: `tf.summary.FileWriter`

Comment: this time I got : TypeError: add_graph() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'graph'

Comment: Iam getting a graph which contains only the init function's graph and not the model :(

Comment: try passing the MODEL_DIR attribute to your model: something like this `model_dir=FLAGS.log_dir`... Maybe this can help you as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663081/how-to-create-a-tensorflow-tensorboard-empty-graph